# Which word is better here: 'case' or 'occasion'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-order

1. I want to say about some event/incident/opportunity (not crime) that happened in city/area.

For example, ***Manchester occasion*** or ***Florida occasion*** meaning some event/incident/opportunity that once happened in Manchester or Florida.

I suppose it is used in detective stories like ***Glasgow case*** or ***Purple jacket case***, but I think ***case*** may be too detective-like.

2. Can I use such word order?
3. Do I need to use ***The***?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'case' in a general way, not just to talk about crimes or police investigations. It just means 'a particular situation or example of something'.

*Strange flying objects were reported in Manchester and Florida. In the Manchester case (or in the case of Manchester), they turned out to be migrating geese, and in Florida, weather balloons.*

> **case noun (SITUATION) Countable**
>
> **A particular situation or example of something:**
>
> *Over a hundred people were injured, in several cases seriously.*
>
> *Jobs are hard to find but in his case that's not the problem because
> he has so much experience.*
>
> *I wouldn't normally agree but I'll make an exception in this case.*
>
> *The number of new cases of the illness appears to be declining.*
>
> *We have lots of applications from people who want to study here and in
> each  case we consider the candidate very carefully.*
>
> *She was suffering from an extreme case of sunburn.*

[Case (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/case)

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou - you need to post that as your own new question.